# Editing larger sound files in Kontakt 5

Tags: editions, samples

I am using NI Kontakt 5 sampler editor. And when I try to delete some unnecessary sounds, the program starts to act like it's working on the removal, but nothing happens.

This happens only with large files .wav above 30 MB
When editing small sound files everything works fine.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Do a low-quality bank, produce the music
than create an analog high-q bank for rendering.
Useful!

Comment: Which version of Kontakt 5 are you using?

Answer (score 1):

When using the Kontakt 5 in a trial or demo mode, there may be a  limit on the size of files it will read. Check the link here, and investigate your setup, you may still be able to play the the larger files. There is mention of getting an  additional activation Serial Number to use.

http://help.timespace.com/home/what-are-kontakt-files-kontakt-libraries

Hope this is of some help to you.  ~catz

Answer (score 0):

Well if you treat your original source recordings having unnecessary bits, then tough tetris.

Have you tried cropping first, and then getting rid of unnecessary bits?